# Define $X:= cube , Y:=coin$ If $Y=H$ the player get $2X$ dollars.If $Y=T$ the player get $\frac{1}{2}X$ dollars. Find the expected value of the gain.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Define $X:= cube , Y:=coin$

If $Y=H$ the player get $2X$ dollars.

If $Y=T$ the player get $\frac{1}{2}X$ dollars.

Find the expected value of the gain.

My solution:

$$P(x,y)=P_x\cdot P_y=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{12}.$$

$$E[2X|Y=H]=2E[X|Y=H]=2\sum_{i=1}^6 x P(x|y)=2\sum_{x=1}^6 x \frac{P(x,y)}{P(y)}=2(1+2+3+4+5+6)\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{12}}{\frac{1}{2}} =2(1+2+3+4+5+6)\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{12}}{\frac{1}{2}}=7$$

$$E[0.5X|Y=T]=0.5E[X|Y=T]=0.5\sum_{i=1}^6 x P(x|y)=0.5\sum_{x=1}^6 x \frac{P(x,y)}{P(y)}=0.5(1+2+3+4+5+6)\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{12}}{\frac{1}{2}} =0.5(1+2+3+4+5+6)\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{12}}{\frac{1}{2}}=1.75$$

$$E=E[2X|Y=H]+E[0.5X|Y=T]=7+1.75=8.75$$

I saw another solution such that the result was different so I want to verify my solution.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gain is $G = f(Y)X$ where $f(H) = 2$ and $f(T) = 1/2$. As $X$ and $Y$ are independent, one has
\begin{equation}
E(G) = E(f(Y)X) = E(f(Y))E(X) = \frac{2 + 1/2}{2}\times 3.5 = 4.375
\end{equation}